# codeigniter hmvc error over the internet

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

I have developed my website in codeigniter hmvc which is working in my localhost. But When i upload to hosting server it gives the following error

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: /var/home2/shariati/public_html/third_party/MX/Loader.php

Line Number: 102
```

I have set the database setting to

```
username as provided by hosting services
database name as provided by the hosting services
host set to localhost
```

have anybody come across this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check all the setting again with the password. This error is only throw if the database setting the not proper. Following points needs to check

- Database name
- User name
- Password
- Host Name